# Uploading of file on Prestashop order page

Tags: file-upload, prestashop

I need to allow uploading a file (pdf or jpg) for customers on the order page (`shopping-cart.tpl`).

How can I make this file upload widget and attach it to the order so it appears in back office.

My Prestashop version is 1.6.0.14

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The only solution I found was this module (not free) http://addons.prestashop.com/es/21373-file-uploads.html</strike>

In another webpage I found the free solution (or atleasts I hope it helps to you): 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/456742-free-module-file-upload-let-customers-upload-other-files-besides-images/

It works in a Prestashop 1.6.x.x with a free, personalized and overloaded theme.

If anyone can find more modules, will be welcome!

You can upload a jpg file by default (activating the option in product page in backoffice), but not a PDF. This is the reason you must use a module, to modify prestashop default "only upload images".
With the module I post in last modification, you can do this, including select the extensions you allow to upload.

Instructions:

```
1. go to the link above.
2. download the module .rar file
3. go to prestashop admin menu>modules>add new module>upload the .rar you just downloaded
4. go to module search input in modules section, search fileupload, and click in install button.
5. Select the extensions you need allow to the users to upload.
6. Check if the "upload/personalization" option is activated for each product you need to allow uploads.
```

NOTE: This module modifies the CORE of Prestashop, can cause inestabilities (I tryied and worked in a 1.6.x.x prestashop at 18/05/2016)